# Cake php newline character

Tags: php, cakephp

i am using the cakephp **paranoid** function but i want it to not strip **new line character**. I tried passing **\n** in allowed chars but it failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make sure you using the correct quotes:

```
echo Sanitize::paranoid($badString,array("\r\n","\n"));
```

Always use double quotes if your sending in escape chars, and if your stripping both returns and newlines make sure that `"\r\n"` comes before, as im sure the function will sanitize int he order of chars passed in.

Answer (score 1):

What syntax are you using? Make sure that `$allowedChars` is an *array* and that you used double-quotes for the newline (single-quotes do not parse escapes like newline):

```
Sanitize::paranoid($badString, array("\n"));
```